# Nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongodb schema.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  created: {
    type: Date,
    Default: Date.now()
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
    // required: "Title Cannot Be Blank",
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
    // required: "Content is required",
    trim: true
  },
  rooms: [
    {
      roomId: "string",
      roomName: "String",
      pic: "string",
      read_count: "string",
      total_count: "string",
      read_notes_count: "string",
      total_notes_count: "string"
    }
  ],
  privatenotes: [
    {
      title: "string",
      desc: "string",
      notes: [
        {
          title: "string",
          time: "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  timetable: {
    day: [
      {
        id: "String",
        time: "String",
        M: "String",
        T: "String",
        W: "String",
        Th: "String",
        F: "String",
        S: "String",
        Su: "String"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

I am trying to update and remove the notes from private notes But it is giving me this error. 
     MongoError: cannot use the part (timetable of timetable.day) to traverse the element ({timetable: [ { day: [ { eight: "Chemistry" } ] } ]})

I have tried this with $ operator now I am trying this with find and save method but not working.

```
 User.findOne({ "_id": data.id},
        function(err, doc) {
            if (doc) {
                var index1;
                for (var i = 0; i < doc.privatenotes.length; i++) {
                    if (doc.privatenotes[i]._id == data.folderId) {
                        index1 = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                var index2;
                for (var j = 0; j < doc.privatenotes[index1].notes.length; j++) {
                    if (doc.privatenotes[index1].notes[j]._id == data.noteId) {
                        index2 = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                doc.privatenotes[index1].notes[index2].title = data.note;
                 doc.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }else{
              console.log('Successfull')
            }
```

How can I edit notes title and remove notes from privarenotes? thanks

Comment: according to your error message problem in `timetable` field please check where you used `timetable` in your function

Comment: I didn't use timetable at any place in my this function.

Comment: have you checked index1 and index2 value is it valid value ?

Comment: yes it is valid I logged it it is valid When I log doc.privatenotes[index1].notes[index2].title after assigning it also gives me updated value but on save I get this error